# Creating graph in Excel using VBA/macro

Tags: excel, ms-access, graph, vba

I created a macro in Excel for creating bar graphs automatically.
Whenever I run it, it gives "smr run time error" and I am not able to figure out what is wrong with my code.

```
Sub CreateGraph()
'
' CreateGraph Macro
''Initialize variables
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim xlsPath As String
Dim xlsFile As String
xlsPath = "H:\"
xlsFile = "text.xls"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=xlsPath & xlsFile

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-81
    Range("A1:B" & lastRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'TEST'!$A$1:$B" & lastRow)
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
    Range("Q111").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me in solving this puzzle please. 
Also for running any macro automatically from SAS, I always have to change the Excel options for "enable all macros" which I suppose is not good. I have seen people creating and running macros without doing this. Can you please tell me how can I run the macros with enabling all macros option in Excel.

Comment: Well, I can see you now accepted a few more answers, so I'm happy I could contribute as a reminder. What about my other questions above? If you don't address them, then it's almost impossible to help you.

Comment: It is not obvious from the question but this about writing to an Excel workbook from Access VBA.  I think "Access-vba" should be added as a Tag but I am only 79% of the way to having the "Retag post" privilege.  I would be grateful if a more reputable visitor added the tag for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code within this version of the answer is essentially unchanged from the previous version.  However, the text has been rewritten to (1) describe my experience of this type of project, (2) answer the true question and (3) better explain the solution.

**My experience of this type of project**

I have been involved in five such projects.  In each case, the client believed they required the automatic creation of charts but detailed discussion revealed that that this was not the requirement.  The clients all published a substantial number of charts per month but most of the charts were the same as last month but with new data.  They needed to automate the provision of new data for the charts.  Every month some charts were revised but this was humans agreeing better ways of presenting the data.  They wanted the 90% of charts that were unchanged to go through without any effort and implementation of the revisions to be as easy as possible.

In this case, the questioner publishes 100 charts per month in the form of an Excel workbook.  The data for these charts comes from an Access database.  The solution allows for the charts to be changed easily but this is to ease the programming and not to provide more than has been requested.

**Release Template.xls**

The solution requires a hand-crafted workbook named Release Template.xls.  This workbook will contain all the charts and the Month 1 data.  The solution creates a copy of this workbook named Release YYMM.xls in which the Month 1 data has been overwritten by the MM/YY data.

Release Template.xls contains a worksheet, Params, which will be deleted from the release version.  This worksheet has a title row and one data row per chart.  There are five columns: Sheet Name, Range, Number of Rows, Number of Columns and SQL command.

Sheet Name and Range define the location of the source data for the chart.

Number of Rows and Number of Columns define the size of the range.  These values should be generated from the range (or vice versa) but this generation is not difficult and its inclusion would complicate the answer for little advantage.

SQL command is the command to be used to extract the data for the chart from the database.  The code below assumes the SQL command generates a Recordset containing data ready to drop into the worksheet.

These parameters could be in the Access database but I believe they fit more logically in the workbook.  These parameters control getting data out of the Access database and into the Excel workbook.  If a chart is changed such that it requires new data, these parameters must be changed to match but no change is required to the code.

**Envelope**

When this code was tested, it was within an Access Module.  It could probably be transferred to a form but that has not been tested.  There MUST be a reference to the "Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library".

This envelope should be suitable for any similar problem.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Control()

  ' This list includes the variables for the envelope and the generation code

  Dim DestFileName As String
  Dim Path As String
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
  Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

  ' I have my Excel file and my Access database in the same folder.
  ' This statement gets me the name of the folder holding my database.
  ' You may need to define a different path.
  Path = Application.CurrentProject.Path

  ' Create path and file name of "Resource YYMM.xls"
  DestFileName = Path & "\" & "Resource " & Format(Date, "yymm") & ".xls"
  ' Create copy of "Resource Template.xls".
  FileCopy Path & "\Resource Template.xls", DestFileName

  Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
  With xlApp
    .Visible = True  ' This slows the macro but helps with debugging
    ' .Visible = False
    Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open(DestFileName)
    With xlWB      

      ' Code to amend "Resource YYMM.xls" goes here

      .Save       ' Save the amended workbook
      .Close      ' Close the amended workbook
    End With
    Set xlWB = Nothing  ' Clear reference to workbook
    .Quit               ' Quit Excel
  End With   Set xlApp = Nothing   ' Clear reference to Excel
End Sub
```

**Code to generate copy data to workbook**

This code assumes it is possible to create SQL statments that will generate Recordsets of data ready to drop into the workbook.

This code has been partially tested.  The tests parameters defined ranges in the workbook which matches the size of the parameters.  The data loaded into Params() was written to these ranges.

```
      Dim DestSheetName As String
      Dim NumCols As Integer
      Dim NumRows As Integer
      Dim OutData() as Variant
      Dim Params() as Variant
      Dim RngDest As String
      Dim RowParamCrnt As Integer
      Dim RowParamMax As Integer
      Dim SQLCommand As String

      With .Sheets("Params")
        ' Find last used row in worksheet
        RowParamMax = .Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' Read entire worksheet into array Params
        Params = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowParamMax, 5)).Value

        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False       ' Surpress delete confirmation
        .Delete                           ' Delete parameters sheet
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

      End With    

      ' Params is an array with two dimensions.  Dimension 1 is the row.
      ' Dimension 2 is the column.  Loading Params from the range is
      ' equivalent to:
      '   ReDim Params( 1 to RowParamMax, 1 to 5)    
      '   Copy data from worksheet to array

      For RowParamCrnt = 2 To RowParamMax

        DestSheetName = Params(RowParamCrnt, 1)
        DestRng = Params(RowParamCrnt, 2)
        NumRows = Params(RowParamCrnt, 3)
        NumCols = Params(RowParamCrnt, 4)
        SQLCommand = Params(RowParamCrnt, 5)

        ' Use the SQL command to create a Recordset containing the data
        ' for the chart. 

        ' Check the Recordset's dimensions against NumRows and NumCols

        ReDim OutData(1 to NumRows, 1 to NumCols)

        ' Note (repeat Note): the first dimension is for rows and the
        ' second dimension is for columns. This is required for arrays
        ' to be read from or to a worksheet.

        ' Move the data out of the Recordset into array OutData.

        .Sheets(DestSheetName).Range(DestRng).Value = OutData

      Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have to create more than 100 graphs every month. using a chart wizard (doing manually) would take a lot of my time. That is why I am using macro to automatically create these.

Comment: Thank You. 
These would be same graphs but with different data every month. Can you tell me how to do that? I have all my data in access database? Sorry if I am asking for too much but I have no idea how to do this, Thanks a ton.

Comment: I ran the code and it gave me error - User defined type not defined for statement "Dim xlApp As Excel.Application". Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you added a reference to Microsoft Excel 11.0 Library?  See paragraph above code?

Comment: @Nupur.  I have revised the answer in a way that I hope is more helpful to you and future readers.  I have deleted my comments which are no longer relevant.  I suggest you do the same.